# mvn package is putting my config .properties file in classpath but I need to put my config.properties file in specific folder after mvn package

Tags: maven, package

I have my config.properties in src/main/resources but after mvn package, config.properties is being pulled to classpath. I am trying to build runnable jar file. After I look into runnable jar file I see config.properties is in classpath. How I can put my config.properties into resources folder. I am getting null pointer because one of jar file which I can't edit is looking this config.properties in /resources folder.

```
Coudn't find XX-XX config file for the filepath:config.properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create the resources folder in your resources folder:

```
src/main/resources/resources/config.properties
```

Everything in src/main/resources is in the classpath root. So the properties file would be in resources/config.properties.

Comment: Cook thanks that was cool trick but didnt help me out it was not the issue. thanks for reply ! Please check my other question if you can explain :)